# Palindrome, isalpha and character counter program

Tags: c++, strings, array, pointers

```
#include <iostream>

const int STRINGSIZE = 100;

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;



void IsPalindrome(char[]);
void IsAlphaStr(char[]);
void CountChar(char[]);

int main()
{
    char string[STRINGSIZE] = {};
    char repeat = NULL;

    cout << "Would you like to perform an analysis on a string of characters(y/n)? ";
    cin >> repeat;
    cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()); //clears the input buffer to make room for a new input from the user.

    while (repeat == 'y' || repeat == 'Y') //loop to repeat the program until the user wants to exit.
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a string of characters: ";
        cin.getline(string, STRINGSIZE); //acquaires the input from the user and stores it in the memory address assigned to string[].
        cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()); //clears the input buffer of the values entered.

        IsPalindrome(string); //Calls to the Palindrome Function below.
        IsAlphaStr(string); //Calls to the alphabetic comparision function below.
        CountChar(string); //Calls to the character counter function below to perform the actions.

        cout << "\nWould you like to perform an analysis on another string(y/n)? ";
        cin >> repeat;
        cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());// also clears the input buffer to make room for the next round of inputs.
    }
        return 0;
}

void IsPalindrome(char string[]) //Checks the string to see if the characters inside are a palindrome.
{
    int stringStart, stringMiddle, stringEnd, length = 0;

    cout << "\n**Palindrome Analysis**" << endl;
    while (string[length] != NULL) //counts the length of the string before the NULL character at the end.
    {
        length++;
    }
    stringEnd = length - 1; //the final position in the register from #0 to #length-1.
    stringMiddle = length / 2; //compares the first half of the string with the last half.

    for (stringStart = 0; stringStart < stringMiddle; stringStart++) //compares the first and last character, the first + 1 and the last -1 characters until the middle is reached.
    {
        if (string[stringStart] != string[stringEnd]) //if the string is not a palindrome, this will be the output.
        {
            cout << "The string: " << string << " is not a palindrome" << endl;
            break;
        }
        stringEnd--;
    }
    if (stringStart == stringMiddle) //confirms the string is a palindrome if the first half is the same as the last half of the string.
    {
        cout << "The string: " << string << " is a palindrome" << endl;
    }
}

void IsAlphaStr(char string[]) //Checks to see if the characters inside the string are all alphabetic or not.
{
    int stringStart;
    int stringLength = 0;

    cout << "\n**Alphabetic Analysis**" << endl;
    while (string[stringLength] != NULL) //counts the characters in the string.
    {
        stringLength++;
    }

    for (stringStart = 0; stringStart < stringLength; stringStart++)
    {
        if (isalpha(string[stringStart])) //compares the character in the string at the incremented point with the ASCII table to make sure it is apart of the alphabet.
        {
            cout << "The character: " << string[stringStart] << " is alphabetic" << endl;

        }
        else //if the character being compared is not apart of the alphabet.
        {
            cout << "The character: " << string[stringStart] << " is not alphabetic" << endl;
        }
    }
    for (stringStart = stringLength - 1; stringStart < stringLength; stringStart++)
    {
        if (isalpha(string[stringStart])) 
        {
            cout << "The string: " << string << " only contains alphabetic characters." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The string: " << string << " contains more than alphabetic characters." << endl;
        }
    }
}

void CountChar(char string[]) //Prompts the user to enter the character or number they wish to count in the string.
{
    int count = 0;
    int stringLength = strlen(string);
    char characterCount = '\0';

    cout << "\nPlease enter the character, or integer, to be counted: ";
    cin >> characterCount;

    for (int start = 0; start < stringLength; start++)
    {
        if (string[start] == characterCount) //takes the character entered by the user to be counted, and increments the count until the loop can't find anymore of the given character.
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout << "The number of times the character: " << characterCount << " appears in the string is: " << count << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is still broken code because some parts of your code does not work as expected.

Comment: @morbidCode fixed my code so it outputs the proper `if` or `else` statement at the bottom of the `IsAlpha` function. Should not be broken code anymore.

Comment: what you can do is debug your code, see why the input is like that, then think of a way to fix it and give the correct input. You'll feel a lot better if you know you found the solution on your own. Then if you want, come back and post the fully working code.

Comment: So now that the code is supposed to be working, before voting to reopen the question, could you please add a little bit more about what the code actually does and what you want to be reviewed? :)

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> void IsPalindrome(char string[]) //Checks the string to see if the characters inside are a palindrome.
> {
> ```

It is easy to miss comments that are to the right of the code.  It is often better to put them on a separate line, e.g.

```
//Checks the string to see if the characters inside are a palindrome.
void isPalindrome(char string[])
{
```

Another advantage of this is that it makes it easy to switch from the having the `{` on a separate line to on the same line.

Note that TitleCase is rare for function names in C++.  It's more common to put them in either camelCase or snake_case.

> ```
>     int stringStart, stringMiddle, stringEnd, length = 0;
>
>     cout << "\n**Palindrome Analysis**" << endl;
>     while (string[length] != NULL) //counts the length of the string before the NULL character at the end.
>     {
>         length++;
>     }
> ```

You don't need to do this.  You can just say

```
    int length = strlen(string);
```

That uses the built-in function to calculate it.

Note that you could also use `std::string` instead of `char []` to hold your string.  That would allow you to say `string.length()`.

> ```
>     stringEnd = length - 1; //the final position in the register from #0 to #length-1.
>     stringMiddle = length / 2; //compares the first half of the string with the last half.
>
>     for (stringStart = 0; stringStart < stringMiddle; stringStart++) //compares the first and last character, the first + 1 and the last -1 characters until the middle is reached.
>     {
>         if (string[stringStart] != string[stringEnd]) //if the string is not a palindrome, this will be the output.
>         {
>             cout << "The string: " << string << " is not a palindrome" << endl;
>             break;
>         }
>         stringEnd--;
>     }
>     if (stringStart == stringMiddle) //confirms the string is a palindrome if the first half is the same as the last half of the string.
>     {
>         cout << "The string: " << string << " is a palindrome" << endl;
>     }
> }
> ```

You can get rid of the last `if` by replacing the `break;` with a `return;`.

```
    //compares the first and last character, the first + 1 and the last -1 characters until the middle is reached.
    for (char *left = string, *right = string + length - 1; left < right; left++, right--) 
    {
        if (*left != *right)
        {
            std::cout << "The string: " << string << " is not a palindrome" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "The string: " << string << " is a palindrome" << std::endl;
}
```

This also means that you no longer have to define your loop variables outside the `for` loop.

I switched from indexes to direct manipulation of character pointers.  This might give a slight performance increase, but the big advantage is that it allows for a simpler loop definition.  Note that the `stringMiddle` variable is no longer necessary.

I also added the `std::` prefix.  This makes it clearer which version you want to call.

I removed a redundant comment.  If you output a string saying that something is not a palindrome, then you don't have to also comment that it is not a palindrome.

> ```
>     int stringStart;
>     int stringLength = 0;
>
>     cout << "\n**Alphabetic Analysis**" << endl;
>     while (string[stringLength] != NULL) //counts the characters in the string.
>     {
>         stringLength++;
>     }
>
>     for (stringStart = 0; stringStart < stringLength; stringStart++)
>     {
>         if (isalpha(string[stringStart]))
>         {
>             cout << "The character: " << string[stringStart] << " is alphabetic" << endl;
>
>         }
>         else 
>         {
>             cout << "The character: " << string[stringStart] << " is not alphabetic" << endl;
>         }
>     }
>     for (stringStart = stringLength - 1; stringStart < stringLength; stringStart++)
>     {
>         if (isalpha(string[stringStart])) 
>         {
>             cout << "The string: " << string << " only contains alphabetic characters." << endl;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             cout << "The string: " << string << " contains more than alphabetic characters." << endl;
>         }
>     }
> ```

You don't need three loops here.  The second `for` loop will actually do the wrong thing.  The first `for` loop can be merged with the `while` loop, as you don't use the `length` that you calculate.

```
    int nonAlphaCount = 0;

    std::cout << "\n**Alphabetic Analysis**" << std::endl;
    for (char *current = string; *current != NULL; current++)
    {
        if (isalpha(*current))
        {
            std::cout << "The character: " << *current << " is alphabetic" << std::endl;

        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "The character: " << *current << " is not alphabetic" << std::endl;
            nonAlphaCount++;
        }
    }

    if (nonAlphaCount > 0) 
    {
        std::cout << "The string: " << string << " contains more than alphabetic characters." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The string: " << string << " only contains alphabetic characters." << std::endl;
    }
```

This will not print that the string contains only alphabetic characters unless it does.  The original code would print incorrectly when the last character was alphabetic but an earlier character was not.  E.g. "a1b".

> ```
> for (int start = 0; start < stringLength; start++)
> {
>     if (string[start] == characterCount) //takes the character entered by the user to be counted, and increments the count until the loop can't find anymore of the given character.
>     {
>         count++;
> ```

In newer versions of C++, you can use a range-based `for` loop here:

```
for (auto c : string)
{
    if (c == characterToCount)
    {
        count++;
```

I also changed `characterCount` to `characterToCount`.  The extra word makes it a lot clearer what the variable holds.

You could also do this with `std::string::find` if `string` were a `std::string` rather than a `char []`.

```
size_t position = string.find(characterToCount);
while (position != std::string::npos)
{
    count++;
    position = string.find(characterToCount, position+1);
```

Comment: Thank you for those critiques! I will have to take a look at my code and see how I can implement some of those. This is a first-term c++ class and we still haven't covered things like `std::string` or pointers yet. Even though I recognize them, I'm still not too familiar with how they work. We should be covering pointers in the next week or so. Also, the reason why I used `IsPalindrome` instead of the normal naming convention is because that is how the assignment wanted them called :/

Answer (score 2):

Just want to emphasize on your comments. They are pretty bad:

> ```
> IsPalindrome(string); //Calls to the Palindrome Function below.
> IsAlphaStr(string); //Calls to the alphabetic comparision function below.
> CountChar(string); //Calls to the character counter function below to perform the actions.
> ```

Bad commenting is **WORSE** than no commenting.

Don't tell me what the code is doing.

> ```
> IsPalindrome(string); //Calls to the Palindrome Function below.
> ```

I can see that this calls a function called `IsPalindrome()` just by reading the code. I don't need a comment to tell me that. This kind of commenting becomes a real problem as the code ages, since code and comments will drift over time (then you have no idea which is correct, and that costs man hours to verify and fix).

Use the technique of self documenting code. Functions/Variable names that help describe what is happening with no need for any additional comments.

```
if (isPalindrome(x)) {
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Don't even need to comment that line. It prints `x` if it is a palindrome.

When you eventually need to write a comment. Your comment should describe **WHAT** you are trying to achieve. The code describes **HOW** you achieve it. So never write comments that could be considered **HOW** descriptions (that just means your code is too ugly to read and you should go back a refactor your code). Alternatively you can use comments to describe **WHY** or provide a link to Wikipedia and/or an article explaining why/what/how.